# Please identify this 6-pin SMD marked AI531

Tags: identification, surface-mount

[image: PCB photo]

It is a 6-pin SMD from 1.6W blue laser driver
The code on the case is AI531
Please help to identify this SMD.

---

https://tr.aliexpress.com/item/33045090236.html?spm=a2g0n.shopcart-amp.item.33045090236

can I use this?                               .

Answer (score 4):

The package marking probably is: "A**1**" followed by "531" in a different font (like image shown below where the code is A1-287).

[image]

Image source: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32810968329.html

$$$$
It likely is the [RT9284A](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT9284A=RT9284B/DS9284AB-07.pdf) from Richtek.

> The RT9284A/B is a compact, high efficient and high integration LED driver. Internal 22V MOSFET can support 2 to 5 White LEDs for backlighting and camera flashing.